# Overlay image on the bottom of a responsive image slider

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an image to the bottom of a responsive slider and need help sticking it to the bottom.

When in full screen mode it works fine, but as I shrink the page it keeps floating up, higher and higher.

I know I can set media queries to fix the issue on certain breakpoints, but I'm looking for a more adaptive solution that will work without having to use media queries.

Here is an image of what the slider looks like at full width. (This is fine.)
[image]

Then as I start to scale the screen you can notice the grass image moving up.

This is my problem. I need that grass to stay glued to the bottom of the slider.
[image]

I don't want to post all the slider code so I made a simple version on JSFiddle.

Here is the code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pic" align="center"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8uVGUkM.jpg" class="slider"/></div>


<div class="grassframe"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vw8soIm.png" class="img-max"/></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider{width:100%; max-width:960px; height:auto;  position:relative; z-index:1;}

.grassframe {
    position:relative;
    max-width:1200px;
    margin:-135px auto;
    z-index:2;
    }
.img-max { width:100%; height:auto; }
```

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daugaard47/sNrN3/3/) if someone wouldn't mind taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `absolute` `position` and `margin-top` with `%` value. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sNrN3/7/)**

Vertical padding or margin using % value use the parent's width as reference. So once tuned it will worke with any width.

```
.slider {
    width:100%;
    max-width:960px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    border:solid;
}
.grassframe {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-12.5%;
    max-width:1200px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:2;
}
.img-max {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

---

If you use a wrapper in relative position and set to same max-width, it even works better *(grass in absolute or relative position doesn't matter much here as long as z-index is avalaible )*: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sNrN3/13/)**

```
.slider {
    width:100%;
    max-width:960px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    border:solid;
}
.grassframe {
    position:relative;
     margin-top:-12%;
    max-width:1200px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:2;
}
.img-max {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.container {
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    max-width:1200px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was needing. The 2nd demo works great. Thank you for helping. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the below code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="pic" align="center">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8uVGUkM.jpg" class="slider" />
    <div class="grassframe"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pic {
    position: relative;
}
.slider {
    max-width:100%;
}
.grassframe {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/vw8soIm.png") no-repeat scroll center top / 1920px auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    bottom: -87px;
    height: 310px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Have a look at the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CsyJE/)

Comment: That's a good idea, but unfortunately I need the image to be in the html img tag. As you see the grass is not scaling in the fiddle and way to large. plus 1 for trying though. You got the sticky part down. Gives me an idea.